# Documenting a django project (django 2 + drf + drf-access-policy)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm documenting a django project that use DRF. I already generated a dynamic API schema using openapi and redoc. Very cool solutions

However, I miss the permissions part in all of this

I have a lot of permissions (permission_classes) in the viewsets and some functions. Do you know any solution to include the permission in the schema, or in a documentation in general?

Going further, how do you document permissions in a APIs in general?

I already have an idea: include the permissions in a custom description in the schema, but it's still dirty

Thanks. José.-

PS: Sorry for the poor english

Answer (score 1):

DRF is in the process of deprecating the use of the `coreapi` package, however currently there is not easy way within that solution to get security schemas to be added to your documentation.

However there is an alternative https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ this tool claims to support extracting these values (but I personally have not used it for that yet).

Comment: "DRF is in the process of deprecating the use of the coreapi package" --> Good to know.

Comment: I think the problem is that permissions aren't considered in the openapi schema.
About drf-yasg, I looked for "permission" in the docs, and only appear info about the schema view permission classes (itself permissions), not the viewsets. Thanks anyway pal